# php deletes output file of shell script (script ran through php)

Tags: php, bash, shell

This is my php code

```
<?php
    $output=$_POST["code"];
    $my_file = '/opt/lampp/htdocs/trans/output/code.c';
    file_put_contents($my_file, $output);
    chmod($my_file, 0777);
    $outpu=shell_exec('./my.sh "{$my_file}"');
?>
```

my.sh is a script which compiles a few cpp files and generates an object file. 
This script roughly take 78 sec to executes.

**My problem is** if the script is executed manually, it successfully generates the object file. Where as when its is ran through php, the object file is generated ( i found it by executing 'ls' in another terminal) but when the php execution stops, it automatically deletes the object file generated.

PS:- I have not written any 'rm' command in script.
     I have set all permissions as well as extended PHP time out.

my.sh contains

```
if [ -f "objectfile" ]
then
echo ""
else
GPP=`which g++`
$GPP -g ../../../../../../someHeader.h  ../../../../../../someCPP.cpp ../../../../../../someCPP.cpp../../../../../../someHeader.h  -I ../../../../../../someInclude -L ../../../../../../someLib  -o  objectfile 

fi
./objectfile
```

Comment: add trailing `2>&1` to see error

Comment: i have redirected error to a text file, it reads:-  my.sh: line 9: ./objectfile: No such file or directory

Comment: adding somewhere `echo $PATH` ?

Comment: nope, infact path is set right as it works perfectly fine when I run it manually

Comment: What happens when you hardcode the path on line 9?  From `./objectfile` to (I am guessing) `/opt/lampp/htdocs/trans/output/objectfile`

Comment: you guessed it right, although it does not change anything